# Time masking input field Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-forms

It may happen due to ignorance I am asking this question. I want code similar to below code

```
<input class="form-control" appTimeMask (change)='calculateMinutes($event, rowIndex)' [(ngModel)]="data.stTime">
```

I followed https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-time-mask to achieve time masked input field. I want the input which is entered in my `ngModel` to be accessed in component file. I also noticed `change()` event doesn't trigger here.

When I access my model value in component file it has value "Invalid Date" whereas i expect complete date object with time I entered from input.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`

Comment: @Viqas, this partially help, but still I cannot bind input value to ngModel

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to:

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm">
   Input com a diretiva: 
   <input appTimeMask name="inputCtrl" formControlName="inputCtrl">
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
reactiveForm= new FormGroup({
    inputCtrl :new FormControl()
  })

ngOnInit(){
    this.reactiveForm.get("inputCtrl").valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(this.reactiveForm.get("inputCtrl").value);
    })
  }
```